# Proof of Itō's lemma for the Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $B=(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a Brownian motion on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$
- $\mathcal P$ be a sequence of countable subsets $$\mathcal P^n:=\left\{\cdots<t_i^{(n)}<t_{i+1}^{(n-1)}<\cdots\right\}$$ of $[0,\infty)$ such that

  - $0\in\mathcal P^n\subseteq\mathcal P^{n+1}$
  - $\sup\mathcal P^n=\infty$
  - $\displaystyle|\mathcal P^n|:=\sup_{t\in\mathcal P^n}\min_{s\in\mathcal P^n:s\ne t}|s-t|\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}0$
- $\mathcal P_T^n:=\mathcal P^n\cap [0,T)$, for $T>0$
- $t':=t_{i+1}^{(n)}\wedge T$, if $t=t_i^{(n)}$

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $$I:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{t\in\mathcal P_T^n}f(B_t)(B_{t'}-B_t)\;.$$  How can we show, that $$\sum_{t\in\mathcal P_T^n}f(B_t)(B_{t'}-B_t)\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}\int_0^Tf(B_s)\;dB_s\tag{1}$$ in probability and why does that imply $$I=\int_0^Tf(B_s)\;dB_s\;\;\;\text{almost surely}\;?\tag{2}$$

---

I've tried the following: Let $T\ge 0$, $H:=f\circ B$ and $$H^n_s(\omega):=\sum_{t\in\mathcal P_T^n}H_t(\omega)1_{(t,t']}(s)\;.$$ Since $B$ is almost surely continuous, $$\left\{B_s:s\in [0,T]\right\}$$ is almost surely compact and thereby $H$ almost surely bounded on $[0,T]$. Hence, each $H^n$ is a elementary predictable process. Now, let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $s\in (0,T]$. Then, there is a unique $t_0\in\mathcal P_T^n$ with $s=t_0'$ and $$H_s^n-H_s=H_{t_0}-H_{t_0'}\;.$$ Since $H$ is almost surely continuous and $|\mathcal P^n|\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}0$, we've got $$H^n_s-H_s\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}0\;\;\;\text{almost surely}\tag{3}$$ for all $s\in (0,T]$. Since $(3)$ holds for all $T>0$, we can conclude $$\left\|H^n-H\right\|\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}0$$ by the *dominated convergence theorem*, where $$\left\|X\right\|^2:=\operatorname E\left[\int_0^\infty X_s^2\;ds\right]\;.$$ Since by the definition of the *Itō integral* for *elementary predictable processes* $$\int_0^\infty H^n\;dB_s=\sum_{t\in\mathcal P_T^n}H_t(B_{t'}-B_t)$$ and by definition of the *Itō integral* for *progressively measurable* processes $$\int_0^\infty H_s\;dB_s=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty H^n\;dB_s\;\;\;\text{in }L^2(\operatorname P)\;,\tag{4}$$ we should be able to conclude $(1)$. Why? Well, $$\int_0^T H\;dB_s\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\int_0^\infty 1_{\left\{s\le T\right\}}H_s\;dB_s\;.$$ **Now, I got still problems to conclude $(2)$**. Sure, we can choose a subsequence of $(H^n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that the convergence in $(4)$ holds almost surely. But does that mean, that $(2)$ holds? For some reasons, I'm unsure.

Comment: what about $f$; is it continuous or differentiable or...?

Comment: Well, continuity doesn't suffice to ensure the existence of the integral. Some additional assumption is needed (boundedness, mean sqaure continuity,...)

Comment: How is $H^n$ related to the sum $\sum f(B_t) (B_{t'}-B_t)$....? And how exactly do you want to apply the dominated convergence theorem? What is your dominating function?

Comment: the constant depends on $\omega $...

Comment: How do you get a uniform bound for all $\omega $? Continuity gives $|H_t (\omega)| \leq c (\omega) $.

Comment: @saz If we additionally assume $$\operatorname E\left[\int_0^Tf(B_s)\;ds\right]<\infty\;,$$ then $H:[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}$ should be bounded, right? Please add this assumption to the proof above. Then, everything should work as stated.

Comment: $H:[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, but $H:[0,T] \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is **not** bounded. In order to apply the dominated convergence theorem, we need some dominating function for all $\omega$ **and** $t \in [0,T]$. (And, by the way, you still haven't told me what's the connection between $H^n$ and the convergence you want to show.)

Comment: Never claimed this. I'm trying to tell you that your proof doesn't work and that most other proofs require some additional assumption on $f$ (such as boundedness, mean-square continuity,...). It might well be that these proofs can be extended using  "standard" stopping techniques.

Comment: If I can show, that $(H^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of elementary predictable processes, i.e. processes of the form $$Y_t(\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_{i-1}(\omega)1_{(t_{i-1},t_i]}(t)\;\;\;\text{for all }\Omega\times[0,\infty)$$ with bounded and $\mathcal F_{t_{i-1}}$-measurable $\xi$ (where $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is the filtration with respect to what $B$ is an adapted Brownian motion),

Comment: and if I can show, that $$\left\|H^n-H\right\|\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}0\;,$$ then by definition of the Itō integral, $\int_0^\infty H\;dB_s$ is the $L^2(\operatorname P)$ limit of the $$\int_0^\infty H^n\;dB_s=\sum_{t\in\mathcal P_T^n}H_t(B_{t'}-B_t)$$

Comment: Ah, I see, I misunderstood your notation. I read $f \circ B$ as $f \bullet B$. However, the issue with the dominated convergence theorem remains.

Comment: Please take a look at *Theorem 7.13* in the link below. They force $f$ to be twice continuously differentiable and use the statement, that I want to show, for $f'$ instead of $f$. The relevant part is below the big equation over two lines. They state, that the sum converges to $\int_0^T H^n\;dB_s$ "by definition" of the Itō integral. This is true only if one can show what I've mentioned. http://people.bath.ac.uk/maspm/book.pdf

Comment: First of all, the fact that the statement is used in a book doesn't mean that it is correct; unfortunately. And again: I don't claim that the statement is not correct. I would try to prove it first for bounded functions (that's easy, given what you have already done) and then extend it via stopping.

Comment: @saz I don't believe, that it's that complicated. They state, that it holds by definition of the Itō integral and in other books, the authors don't even mention that.

Comment: Lots of authors don't feel like doing and/or explaining all the technical details. So what? Good luck in finding an easier proof.

Comment: @saz Maybe $L^2(\operatorname P)$-convergence doesn't hold. But, as stated in the question, I only need convergence in probability. Does that change anything?

Answer (score 3):

No, we cannot apply the dominated convergence theorem in this way (see all the comments above).

For fixed $R>0$ denote by

$$\tau := \inf\{t>0; |B_t| \geq R\}$$

the exit time from $(-R,R)$. Moreover, we denote by

$$H \bullet B(T) := (H \bullet B)(T) := \int_0^T H(s) \, dB_s$$

the stochastic integral of $H$. By Markov's inequality and Itô's isometry,

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(|H^n \bullet B(T)-H \bullet B(T)| \geq \epsilon) &\leq \mathbb{P}(|H^n\bullet B(T)-H\bullet B(T)| \geq \epsilon, \tau > T) + \mathbb{P}(\tau \leq T) \\ &\leq  \mathbb{P}(|H^n\bullet B(T \wedge \tau)-H\bullet B(T \wedge \tau)| \geq \epsilon) + \mathbb{P}(\tau \leq T) \\ &\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^{T \wedge \tau} |H^n(s)-f(B_s)|^2 \, ds \right) + \mathbb{P}(\tau \leq T). \end{align*}$$

Since $f|_{[-R,R]}$ is bounded, we can let $n \to \infty$ using the dominated convergence theorem and the continuity of $f$ and obtain

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(|H^n \bullet B(T)-H \bullet B(T)| \geq \epsilon) \leq \mathbb{P}(\tau \leq T).$$

Finally, we can let $R \to \infty$ and conclude

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(|H^n \bullet B(T)-H \bullet B(T)| \geq \epsilon)=0.$$

This shows that

$$\begin{align*} I &:=\mathbb{P}-\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{t \in P_T^n} f(B_t) (B_{t'}-B_t)  \\ &= \mathbb{P}-\lim_{n \to \infty} (H^n \bullet B)(T) \\ &= \int_0^T H(s) \, dB_s = \int_0^T f(B_s) \, dB_s \end{align*} $$

almost surely.

Comment: What do you mean by $ \mathbb{P}-\lim$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d limit in probabiliy